# Configure STOMP over websocket in Wildfly 9

Tags: websocket, hornetq, stomp, wildfly-9

I need to configure STOMP over websocket inside wildfly 9. What I did so far,

1. After following help on the internet, I added connectors/acceptores in standalone-full.xml for configuring STOMP over websocket. The configuration looks as follow:

And adde socket-bindings for the same (port 61614).

With this configuration, wildfly 9 starts. But I am not able to connect to STOMP over websocket. Trying to connect using java websocket client over ws://localhost:61614/stomp. But not able to connect using the same. I also tried using the javascript STOMP client library to connect. But result is same and not able to connect using same. (As described here, http://jmesnil.net/stomp-websocket/doc/)

Now after this, I tried adding STOMP_WS protocol on acceptor configuration:

But when I start Wildfly 9 with this, I results in error saying "Error instantiating remoting acceptor org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.netty.Netty.NettyAcceptorFactory: HornetQException[errorType=GENERIC_EXCEPTION message=HQ119085: Classpath lacks a protocol-manager for protocol STOMP_WS]"

One other thing is when I start wildflly 9, I see following lines in logs,

10:37:33,866 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) HQ221043: Adding protocol support CORE
10:37:33,878 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) HQ221043: Adding protocol support AMQP
10:37:33,881 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) HQ221043: Adding protocol support STOMP

But I don't see same for STOMP_WS protocol.

So my question is,
1. How to configure STOMP_WS in wildfly 9?
2. If I only configure STOMP with netty connector/acceptor, does that mean it is STOMP over websocket?

I have tried all this in Wildfly 8,9 and 10 and same things is observed in each versions.

Any help is very much appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is fixed after changing Netty jar in Wildfly 9. Earlier it was netty-all-4.0.26.Final.jar. I replaced it with netty-all-4.0.13.Final.jar. Now I am able to connect to STOMP over websocket with following configuration:

```
                <netty-acceptor name="netty-acceptor" socket-binding="netty">
                    <param key="protocols" value="STOMP"/>
                </netty-acceptor>
```

NOTE: I didn't use STOMP_WS protocol.